# What is this 6-pin IC? Is it an LED driver?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, identification

I have this power recliner which has an LED cup holder. It is a black plastic cup. Once removed, it shows a clear plastic ring with a C shape circuit board with parts on it.

One of the ICs has 6 pins with W502 on it but I think that it is a year/date code.

[image]

Comment: My eyes aren't the greatest. Can you mark the 6-pin IC... maybe add a close-up in a higher resolution.

Comment: please add a picture of the IC ... make sure that the IC label is clearly legible

Answer (score 4):

Given the presence of an inductor nearby, it's most likely a DC-DC converter of some kind.

With a bit of searching, this is potentially Techcode Semi [TD1465](http://www.techcodesemi.com/datasheet/TD1465.pdf). Without a close up, it is hard to tell for sure.

The datasheet doesn't give marking information, but this was identified via the following image found via search engine, which shows marking W502 as you have.

The page the image comes from (link below the image) is a component bazaar like website which lists the image, the marking code, and TD1465 as the part number, so I can't attest to the accuracy, nor the longevity of the link.

[image: W502 Marking]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.taobao.com/list/item/618412196382.htm?spm=a21wu.10013406.taglist-content.12.283877fapWcSWh)</sup>

It has the following pinout which could be compared along with the typical application circuit in the datasheet above with your circuit to see if they are a realistic match, but even from the fuzzy image you show, it does seem to match.

[image: Pinout of TD1465]

[image: Possible Circuit]

Comment: Thank you for your help  it is exactly as in your image, W502  which I think is date code.

Comment: @mikercana1 most likely W5 is the marking for the specific product, and 02 a date code, but can't say for sure (can find other images for TD1465 which have marking W55J, W523, etc).